# ComposeView with dynamic height flickering inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a ComposeView inside a ConstraintLayout like that:

```xml
    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

And this ComposeView expands with `AnimatedVisibility`. I am getting a visual glitch that I can't figure out what is causing it.

When I use the same component inside a Compose activity, without the ComposeView integration, it works fine

Since I can not upload a video here in stackoverflow, I created a minimal example to reproduce it and put a video on README at github https://github.com/GabrielLasso/jetpack-compose-flickering/tree/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

And it worked